# Django progressive web app gives an error in all browsers after caching files

Tags: javascript, django, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, django-cache

I was following this tutorial to make my website a PWA website using django-progressive-web-app. However, when I opened the app from firefox I get the following error:

```
Oops.

The site at http://localhost:8000/ has experienced a network protocol violation that cannot be repaired.

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.

    Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

When I open from Safari I get this error:

```
Safari Can't Open the Page
SAfari can't open the page "http://localhost:8000/base_layout/". The error is: "Response served by service worker has redirections" (WebKitInternal:0)
```

I don't have chrome so I can't tell what is the error there, also running it from private -Incognito- window would solve the problem (and clearing data) So the problem is clearly with the cached code

How can i fix?

## My code

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'pwa',
...
]
   ...
 # Pwa settings
    PWA_SERVICE_WORKER_PATH = os.path.join(
        BASE_DIR, 'static/chat/js', 'serviceworker.js')
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('webpush/', include('webpush.urls')),
    path('', chat_views.home, name="home"),
    path('', include('pwa.urls')),
     path('base_layout/', chat_views.base_layout, name="base_layout"),
   ...
]
```

serviceworker.js (path: Orgachat/static/chat/js/serviceworker.js

```
var staticCacheName = 'djangopwa-v1';

self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function (cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/base_layout'
            ]);
        })
    );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    var requestUrl = new URL(event.request.url);
    if (requestUrl.origin === location.origin) {
        if ((requestUrl.pathname === '/')) {
            event.respondWith(caches.match('/base_layout'));
            return;
        }
    }
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        })
    );
});
```

Finally base.html:

```
{% load pwa %}
...
{% progressive_web_app_meta %}
...
```